# How can I fetch the last row I inserted using DBI?

Tags: perl, dbi

How can I fetch the last row that was inserted using [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI) ([DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD::mysql))?

Code sample:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO a ( x, y, z ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )');
$sth->execute( $x, $y, $z );
```

How can I get access to the data that was inserted by the above `prepare` statement? I need to get the primary ID (`AUTOINCREMENT`) value.

**UPDATE:**

From [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD::mysql) documentation:

> An alternative way for accessing this
>   attribute is via
>   `$dbh->{'mysql_insertid'}`.

Thank you [Manni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7498/manni) and [n0rd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31782/n0rd) for your answers. :-)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is a property of the statement handle. You should be able to access the ID like that:

```
$sth->{mysql_insertid}
```

Comment: `$dbh->{mysql_insertid}` returns the same.

Comment: Couldn't you get a different answer, if there was an insert between your insert and this call?

Comment: Of course. Your supposed to query `$sth->{ mysql_insertid }` immediately after the INSERT statement your interested in.

Comment: Rephrasing something that was said below. . . I believe what Sam is asking is whether the window between inserting and retrieving could have an intervening insert from an outside process.  Yes it could, but the mysql_insertid (and don't try this on oracle) is the last insert that *your session* executed, so no worries there.

Answer (score 34):

A database agnostic approach is to use the [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI)'s [`last_insert_id`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#last_insert_id) method. This approach helps to reduce dependency on a specific database:

> ### $dbh->last_insert_id
>
> `$rv = $dbh->last_insert_id($catalog, $schema, $table, $field);`
>
> Returns a value 'identifying' the row just inserted, if possible. Typically this would be a value assigned by the database server to a column with an auto_increment or serial type. Returns undef if the driver does not support the method or can't determine the value.

Comment: Some DBD drivers work with just `$dbh->last_insert_id()` (e.g., DBD::MariaDB).

Answer (score 6):

`SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` [query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) will also return what you want.

Comment: @Anthony that is incorrect. LAST_INSERT_ID() is related only to *your current* mysql connection and is unaffected by what anybody else are doing on your server.

Comment: Underlying DBI driver maybe not mysql