# How can I call a mysql function (like mysql_insert_id) from Perl if i'm using DBI/DBD?

Tags: mysql, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fetch the last row I inserted using DBI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906896/how-can-i-fetch-the-last-row-i-inserted-using-dbi)

I need to be able to call functions in mysql. One example is:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect(......)
$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO xxx VALUES ......";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sqlQuery);
$sth->execute();

#The missing code is here
#Call the function mysql_insert_id to retrieve the id of the last inserted record
#Do something with the id
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Thanks Mat. I used the solution suggested in the indicated post which is: $insertedId = $sth->{mysql_insertid}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from `perldoc DBI`:

```
$rv = $dbh->last_insert_id($catalog, $schema, $table, $field);
```

Answer (score 2):

documentation: https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#last_insert_id

```
my $id = $dbh->last_insert_id();
```

parameters are ignored for MySQL

Comment: I'm getting: Can't locate object method "mysql_insert_id" via package "DBI::db" at ...

Comment: it's `last_insert_id`, not `mysql_insert_id`

Comment: oh sorry, my bad. It seems though that ignoring the arguments depends on the driver version coz in my case it complained about the number of arguments. Thanks a lot.