# How to get the record number returned for a MySQL insert command in Perl

Tags: mysql, perl

I am inserting into a MySQL table from Perl.  But sometimes I would like to get the record number for that insert to use later.

Is there a way to get that return from MySQL?

p.s. This table has zero indexes.

Thanks

Comment: How do you proceed to insert into the database table ? Please share a code snippet so we can analyse and suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no indexes, there is no record number.  Well, there will be a hidden primary key, but no access to it.

Normally you would have an explicit primary key, and if it is set to auto increment, it will be available via the statement handle.  See [How can I fetch the last row I inserted using DBI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906896/how-can-i-fetch-the-last-row-i-inserted-using-dbi)